# How do I run playwright targeting localhost in github-actions?

Tags: next.js, github-actions, playwright

I am trying to run playwright E2E tests for github-actions but have been unsuccessful so far.

```
    - name: Run build and start
      run: |
        yarn build:e2e
        yarn start:e2e &
    - name: Run e2e
      run: |
        yarn e2e
```

I don't think the server is running when `playwright` runs because all the e2e tests end up failing.

**Run build and start**

```
Done in 192.91s.
yarn run v1.22.19
$ env-cmd -f environments/.env.e2e next start
ready - started server on 0.0.0.0:3000, url: ***
```

**Run e2e**

```
Test timeout of 270000ms exceeded while running "beforeEach" hook.
```

I am pretty certain that playwright cannot connect to `http://localhost:3000` from the previous step and that's why all the tests timeout.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a similar problem and I fixed it by adding this to playwright.config.ts

```
const config: PlaywrightTestConfig = {
// the rest of the options
  webServer: {
    command: 'yarn start',
    url: 'http://localhost:3000/',
    timeout: 120000,
  },
  use: {
    baseURL: 'http://localhost:3000/',
  },
  // the rest of the options
};
export default config;
```

Also, I didn't need to yarn start in GitHub Actions workflow, just yarn build is enough.

Source:
https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/14814